# Phonegap (Cordova) jQuery Ajax Login

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, cordova

Alright, so I'm using jQuery and Cordova to try and login to a mySQL database. Having some issues maybe someone can help me out with.

```
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.mobile-1.1.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        function login() {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                              var user = $("#user")[0].value;
                              var pass = $("#pass")[0].value;
                              $.ajax({
                                     type: "GET",
                                     url: "http://www.greekhighlight.com/mob_login.php",
                                     data: "users"+user+"&pass="+pass,
                                     success: function(result){
                                     if (value){
                                     $("#message")[0].value = "Success "+result;
                                     } else {
                                     $("#message")[0].value = "error";
                                     }
                                     });

        }
                              };
        </script>
```

Here is my javascript in the head tag.

```
        <form>
        Username: <input type="text" size="25" id="user" onkeyup= "login()" />
        <br />
        Password: <input type="text" size="25" id="pass" onkeyup= "login()"/>
        <br />
        <input type="text" size="25" id="message" value="error" />
        </form>
```

Here is my HTML form.

```
<?php
$user = $_REQUEST['user'];
$pass = $_REQUEST['pass'];
include('php/connect.php');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT email, password, userid FROM users WHERE email = '$user'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
if(md5($pass) == $row["password"]){
    echo $row["userid"];
} else {
    echo "";
}
} 
?>
```

And here is my PHP file.

This is my first experience in using Phonegap and such, so I hope this is not something I am just overlooking. My connect file is correct. And the tutorial I was following had success, so I am not sure as to why mine is not.

If someone can just give me a push in the right direction, I hope I can figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** Decided to use Aurigma Up and just a mobile version of the site since this project is just in the beginning stages. Will hopefully come back to this problem at some point and make it work correctly. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: why you are using onkeyup to fire the function why not adding the button with onclick every time you type something it fires the js even-though some fields like password are blank

Comment: That is how it was in the tutorial. It is supposed to be an "instant" result, just as an example really. I understand what you are saying though, that would be how it should be in the end. But, if it is not working the instant way, unfortunately it will not then either.

I could try and do an onClick just to see though.

Comment: You can still try I would start by testing it with onclick on the web

Comment: Tried it with just a simple button onclick to run the login() function.. Still nothing.

Comment: I found this earlier on an actual page.. But could not find it again. Then saw it on YouTube and decided to try again. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IrFxLOffgNg

Comment: Should there be a ? where it says data: Such as ?user=

Comment: hold on let me write you some example

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with your code:

1. You should probably use `POST` for this request and I assume you want to use the `result` value in your success function check (maybe consider returning a JSON obj with `status`).
2. Your `ajax.data` should be more along this line `{"user":user,"pass":pass}`
3. Your php code is insecure and should use prepared statements.
4. Storing a password as `md5(password)` is a big **no no** these days, do some research on better/secure hash functions.
5. Your login event is `onkeyup`

**Some examples to point you in the right direction**

HTML:

```
 ...
 <input type="text" size="25" id="pass"/>
 ...
 <input type="button" id="#login_button" value="Login">
 ...
```

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#login_button').click(function() {
         // ... ajax request here ...
     });
 });
```

PHP:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT email, password, userid, salt FROM users WHERE email = ?');
$stmt->bind_param($email);
$stmt->bind_result($hash,$salt);
$stmt->execute();
if ($stmt->fetch_result()) {
     if (hash('sha512',$password.$salt)==$hash) {
         // ... OK ...
     }
}
```

Goodluck.

Notes:
[PHP prepared statement reference](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), Google "secure password storage with salt", Play around on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Your post is very insightful and I will be reading this article. Hopefully can implement this. I'm going to take a break for now cause I am still having issues and hit it tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

try this I would also make sure you use some protection against query injections on your php end

html

```
 <form>
    Username: <input type="text" size="25" id="user" onkeyup= "login()" />
    <br />
    Password: <input type="text" size="25" id="pass" onkeyup= "login()"/>
    <br />
    <input type="text" size="25" id="message" value="error" />
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="login()"/>
    </form>
```

javascript

```
function login() {
            $(document).ready(function() {
           var user = $("#user").val();
           var pass = $("#pass").val();
     $.ajax({
            url: "http://www.greekhighlight.com/mob_login.php",  
            type: "GET",        
            data: { username: user, password: pass }     
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {  
                alert(html);      
            }   
          });
       });
}
```

and your php

```
 <?php
    $user = $_GET['username'];
    $pass = $_GET['paswords'];
    include('php/connect.php');

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT email, password, userid FROM users WHERE email = '$user'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if(md5($pass) == $row["password"]){
        echo $row["userid"];
    } else {
        echo "";
    }
    } 
    ?>
```

Comment: Still having trouble with it.. Going to take a break for the night. Thanks again for great post. Will keep working at it tomorrow and hopefully have an answer mark for you.